# open file txt by notepad++ default java code

Tags: java, swt

```
String cmds[] = new String[] { "cmd", "/c","C:\Test.txt" };
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmds);
```

Currently, I use the above code to open a txt file on local.
However, it will be opened by notepad and not be kept the original format .
I want to open default by notepad++ to fix this.
Please tell me the way to process this case.
Thanks.

Comment: Is notepad++ a default program for .txt files in your system?

Comment: try { "cmd", "/c","notepad++ C:\Test.txt" };

Comment: @Satya's comment is relevant, but you may have cases where the `notepad++` command isn't recognized by the command line, e.g. the path variable isn't set.

Comment: in that case, he will have to use full path of notepad++.exe , posting as answer

Comment: What's your fallback solution of Notepad++ is not installed?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Desktop.getDesktop().open(file)`, **but** it takes the default system application for opening the specified file.

The advantage to this API is its platform independency.

However, you really need to thoroughly think about what you're going to do if:

Notepad++ installed, but not default program for `.txt` files

Notepad++ present, but not installed

---

**Additional info from [WVrock](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3009607/wvrock)**

> I want to point out that it is possible to use edit() instead of open() to open it with the system's default editing application instead of opening application. Note that an average user doesn't know how to change default editing application and it is usually set to notepad in windows.

Comment: I want to point out that it is possible to use `edit()` instead of `open()` to open it with the system's default editing application instead of opening application. Note that an average user doesn't know how to change default editing application and it is usually set to notepad in windows.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("Notepad++.exe", "myfile.txt");
pb.start();
```

OR

```
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process process = runtime.exec("C:\\path\\to\\notepad++.exe C:\\path\\to\\file.txt");
```

For example, if notepad++ is located at `C:\Windows\notepad++.exe`:

```
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process process = runtime.exec("C:\\Windows\\notepad++.exe C:\\test.txt");
```

Go to your notepad++ properties and see the path

Answer (score 1):

```
            try {
                String cmds[] = new String[] { "cmd", "/c","C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Notepad++\\notepad++.exe " , "C:\\Test.txt" };
                Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmds);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: I had the same issue and was able to solve it with the code above. Make sure you change it accordigly depending on the location of your notepad++.exe. Also remember  that Test.txt can be anywhere ... you just need to give the path name (i do it by right clicking on it and going to properties ... path should be ready for the trusty copy and paste treatment :))

Answer (score 0):

Right click on that `txt` file and go properties and change open with to `notepad++`. Now run your code and you can see now that file open in notepad++.

First case your computer use `notepad` as default text editor and by doing above steps it will change to `notepad++`

Comment: yes, however, I want to open in other machines. so, I want to open by notepad++ default without changing as above.

Answer (score 0):

```
{ "cmd", "/c","notepad++ C:\Test.txt" };
```

should work , however in case you do not have notepad++ added in PATH the command will be

```
{ "cmd", "/c","fullpath-to-notepad++.exe C:\Test.txt" };
```

Comment: I hope the *other* machines @user2659694 will use the code on, will also run Windows. Because, different operating systems require different commands. He will have to have a separate method to return a command depending on the OS.